# ui.selected is returning undefined when used with a table

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

Alert(id) is returning nothing when used in a table. When I use jquery selectable on "OL" tag it returns the id of the "li", when I change the "ol selectable" to "table selectable", it starts showing empty in the alert message. Do I need to anything different when using table with a jquery UI selectable versus "ol" . Please suggest.

```
 $("#selectable").selectable({
   selected: function (event, ui) {
   var id = $(ui.selected).attr("id");
   var color = $(ui.selected).css("border-color");
   alert(id);
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this filter: "td" helped achieve what I wanted to. I got the answer from jquery forum
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-selectable-as-table-not-returning-id
Credit goes to Jakecigar